# NightwatchJS method .resizeWindow not working

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, nightwatch.js, window-resize

A while back, I had an issue using the `.maximizeWindow()` from NightwatchJS. I was able to resolve this issue by using the following:

```
"chromeOptions" : {
  "args" : ["start-maximized"]
},
```

However, this was more a work around than a fix. Currently, I need to resize the window, not just maximize it, and want to use the `.resizeWindow()` method. I also need this to work in browsers other than Chrome, so the above fix is inadequate. Below is my current setup in a test I am writing. This code worked fine in the past and just recently I noticed that the window was no longer resizing correctly. Any thoughts on why it might be failing? Note: this is written in Coffeescript, not JS.

```
module.exports = {
"Geoprocessing Commands and Assert Tests": (browser) ->
    browser
    .launchAs "anonymous"
    .assert.title "<app name>"
    .iFrameReady()
    .frame 0, () ->
        browser
        .resizeWindow 1800, 1000
        .pageDisplayed()
        .pause 1000
        ...

        .frameParent()

    browser.end()
}
```

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but it looks to me like you are selecting the frame and resizing the the iframe. Is there any reason that you can't try resizing right after .iFrameReady() ( and outsize the .frame)?

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't seem to have any effect.